# What is the result of (271698268*271698267)/2?

Tags: python, complex-multiplication, machine-precision

I need the answer in non-scientific form, to precision. The problem is I'm getting different results from different methods.

| Method | Output | Output (plain) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Python `(271698268*271698267)/2` | `3.6909974281250776e+16` | `36909974281250776` |
| Python `(271698268*271698267)//2` | `36909974281250778` | `36909974281250778` |
| Node `271698268*271698267)/2` | `36909974281250776` | `36909974281250776` |
| Google Sheets `=(271698268*271698267)/2` | `36,909,974,281,250,800.00` | `36909974281250800` |
| Gnome Calculator `(271698268*271698267)/2` | `36909974281250778` | `36909974281250778` |
| LibreOffice Calc `=(271698268*271698267)/2` | `3.69099742812508E+016` | `36909974281250800` |

Various other calculators are only showing me the scientific notation, without the precision I need.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Without computing the full product, we know $(?68*??7)/2 = (??4*??7) = ??8$, so the correct answer need to end at a $8$.

Comment: I would have tried [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28271698268*271698267%29%2F2).

Comment: In Python way seems firstly is precise to calculate $271698268//2=135849134$ and then $135849134*271698267=36909974281250778$. We avoided floating number operation.

Comment: Much more useful than this result is to understand the properties of computer numbers that lead to the problem.

Comment: Better use PARI/GP for arithmetics involving large numbers.

Comment: @RossMillikan - you comment remind me one of the most famous article in computer science: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), I think this should also apply to every mathematicians who use floating point numbers on a computer. The best course of action for OP is read above article and then learn to use a CAS (any CAS which worth a dime will support multiple-precision integer arithmetic) or an arbitrary-precision floating-point package (eg. mpmath in python) to compute the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{271698268\cdot271698267}{2}=36909974281250778$$